# Find all Delicious posts using Yahoo! Pipes from ALL users

Tags: api, search, yql, yahoo-pipes, delicious-api

I'd like to try to create a Yahoo Pipe that will return ALL of the articles, urls, and # of saves on Delicious which are tagged with the category, for instance, 'sushi'.

Is that possible?  (I know I can do it with my own tags, or with those in my network.  And I know I can simply go to Delicious and push the load more button until I exhaust the list.)

But a json structure or an XML output file would be so much easier to process.

Would anybody have a clue how to get this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access delicious data in your application, you’ll need to get a Yahoo! API key and configure it to use delicious social bookmarking. You can do this by creating a project for your application.  https://developer.apps.yahoo.com/dashboard/createKey.html

There are examples at this second link showing something similar to what you are trying to do.

Read more here:
http://developer.yahoo.com/delicious/